GORM enum type for postgres
I use GORM to work with PostgreSQL.
For example I have a such struct with custom enum type:
type MonitoringDatabase struct {
    Name              string       `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    DBType            DbType       `gorm:"type:db_type"`
}

I create Enum using Exec in the scheme i need:
type DbType string

const (
    PostgreSQL DbType = "PostgreSQL"
    Oracle     DbType = "Oracle"
    Ignite     DbType = "Ignite"
)

_, errDbEnum := sqlDB.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("CREATE TYPE %s.db_type AS ENUM ('%s','%s','%s')", PgSchema, PostgreSQL, Oracle, Ignite))


But when migrating the table, I get an error (type "db_type" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42704)) because GORM is looking for enum in the public schema.
I've tried to set search_path and configure NamingStrategy, but it doesn't helps. Schema name is a dynamic parameter, hardcoding it in a tag is not an option
Are there any solutions on how to defeat this problem?

this one is good sample, my answer is based on it(note Scan and Value methods implemented for Enum type):
package main

import (
    "database/sql/driver"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type DbType string

const (
    PostgreSQL DbType = "PostgreSQL"
    Oracle     DbType = "Oracle"
    Ignite     DbType = "Ignite"
)

func (st *DbType) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        *st = DbType(b)
    }
    return nil
}

func (st DbType) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return string(st), nil
}

func (st DbType) TableName() string {
    return "schema_name.db_type"
}

type MonitoringDatabase struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID     uint
    Name   string
    DBType DbType `gorm:"type:schema_name.db_type;default:'PostgreSQL'"`
}

func main() {
    dsn := `postgresql://user:pass@db_server:5432/db_name?connect_timeout=10&application_name=TestEnum`

    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        // fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }

    db.Debug().Exec(`
    DO $$ BEGIN
        CREATE TYPE schema_name.db_type AS ENUM ('PostgreSQL','Oracle','Ignite');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
    END $$;`)

    md := MonitoringDatabase{}
    err=db.AutoMigrate(&md)
    if err != nil {
        // fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }
    md1 := MonitoringDatabase{
        DBType: PostgreSQL,
    }
    err=db.Debug().Create(&md1)
    if err != nil {
        // fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(md1)
}


Thanks a lot for the research, but unfortunately nothing works, still this solution requires to explicitly specify the database schema in the type tag
